# Using 'tedious' to mean 'annoying'

Tags: meaning, british-english, dialects

Some of my British friends use the word '*tedious*' to mean '*annoying*.' A recent example:

> The museums in Oslo aren't open on Mondays. That's a bit **tedious.**

I'm a native American English speaker and unfamiliar with this usage. I looked it up and only found the [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tedious) I'm familiar with :

> Too long, slow, or dull; tiresome or monotonous

Is this a British variation on the definition that is known in the United Kingdom but that hasn't entered dictionaries yet?

Comment: I've always understood that usage to imply the sense of "*tiresome*", as in "*I'm tired of it; I've had enough; I wish it would stop*".

Comment: @DanBron That's how I would interpret/use it, and I'm an American.

Comment: @DanBron, which usage do mean? In my example sentence, it doesn't mean "tiresome" -- there's nothing tiresome about museums that *aren't* open

Comment: @MarZum I meant it in your sense of "annoying", as in "Bob's behavior is a bit *tedious*", which doesn't mean "*monotonous*", it means "*annoying*".

Comment: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tedious) gets as far as << British English: **tedious**: If you describe something such as a job, task, or situation as tedious, you mean it is boring and rather **frustrating**. [bolding mine]

Comment: It seems that people who say this are over-generalizing. It's generally annoying to perform a tedious task, so they think of _tedious_ as referring to this resulting annoyance, not the boredom that causes it.

Comment: If this catches on, you may be seeing language evolution in progress. Many words have changed meaning over time through this precise process of generalization or specialization.

Comment: I note that Eric Partridge, _Dictionary of Slang & Unconventional English_, fifth edition (1961) lists a meaning of the noun _bore_ (from 1778) as "A boring thing, an annoyance"; and a meaning of the verb _bore_ (from 1925) as "To annoy." Perhaps the lesson here is that the distance between ennui and annoyance may be shorter than we suspect. In any case, I haven't seen or heard _tedious_ used with quite the same implication of "annoying" in U.S. English as in the OP's quoted example.

Comment: Tedious has been used in BrE and AmE to mean annoying or tiresome for quite some time. This is nothing new, and I'm surprised so many people seem to marvel at such a mundane usage.

Comment: This example seems to stretch the meaning of the word a bit but it still seems to fit within the confines of the lexical definition because the museums are always scheduled to be closed on the same weekday. If Mondays are your only available days to visit, you would be enduring the boredom of being unable to visit the museum on a long-term (permanent) basis. Would you please give us another quotation, to demonstrate that this use does not relate to time?

Comment: @Mar Zum  What is tiresome about museums's that aren't open is that they should be open when I want them open but never are.  It's just another example of how things don't go my way.  The people who use tiresome in this sense have the implicit view that the world is organized against them.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to access the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/198523?redirectedFrom=tedious#eid), and Def. #2 is as follows:

> 2. Wearisome in general; annoying, irksome, troublesome, disagreeable, painful. Obs. exc. dial.

This does confirm that this is a known meaning then, but is limited to dialects.

Answer (score 0):

"Is this a British variation on the definition that is known in the United Kingdom but that hasn't entered dictionaries yet?" - No.
As a native speaker of British English my interpretation of the example given is stating that the lack of open museums is rather dull and implying the available alternatives may not be as interesting. Whether or not that is 'annoying' per se would depend on the individual.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is based on US Military theaters of operation around the world.  I speak two other languages besides English (Spanish and Korean).  My Korean is terrible.  My Spanish is rusty.  At one time I conducted instruction in Spanish at IAAFA (Inter-American Air Forces Academy, Panama, RP).  Exposure to cultures is really just that - exposure.  With it came awareness of the culture.  With the awareness came thought processes, i.e. traditions, likes, dislikes, predictable behavior (especially in the language), it reveals a lot about the "natives" thinking. In this sense the use of 'tedious' is vernacular.  If in Los Angeles, you might hear "sh__t!  In New York you might hear "fu__k!'
Anywhere one travels in the world today, and, they stay long enough in one place, they'll learn the dirty words first.... because those are the ones they'll hear most often (trust me).

Comment: Is any of this related to the question?